# React Native Webview (camera, getUserMedia) double request of permissions on iOS 15

Tags: ios, react-native, getusermedia, react-native-webview, react-native-permissions

**What we do?**

We are building a React Native application for both iOS and Android platforms. The application has an external website with camera manipulations inside, opened via **react-native-webview** module. From our experiments we observed that to make it work we **have to ask end-user the camera permissions twice**:

1. (Once) when user firstly open the application after installation on
   his/her device
2. (Every time) when React Native webview component is
   loaded and the getUserMedia method is executing inside it.

Both requests show to the user popups with text to allow camera access: the first for “application_name” and the second is for “url_inside_webview” -
[picture scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfJr3.jpg)

**It is a critical issue for us because:**

1. Asking permissions (inside webview) every time user opens the app
   webview component (and it’s executing) is a bad UX.
2. We faced a rejection on application release to Apple Store during
   Apple review. The comment of reviewer pointed to exactly this moment
   about “asking permissions twice and every time the web component
   loads”

**Technical details to reproduce the issue**

OS: Apple iOS 15.1 and newer

**React Native Dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-native": "0.66.0",
  "react-native-permissions": "^3.0.6",
  "react-native-webview": "^11.14.0"
}
```

**Setup permissions in react-native:**

```
import { request, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS } from 'react-native-permissions';
// ... //
request(PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA)
    .then((statuses) => {
        if (statuses[PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA] === RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            setWebviewRenderAvailable(true);
        });
    });
```

**Configuring in ios/Podfile:**

```
target 'MyAwesomeProject' do
  # Check permissions for camera

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary"

end
```

**Update Info.plist:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

  <!-- ... -->
  <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Camera Access</string>
  <!-- ... -->

</dict>
</plist>
```

**Start webview:**

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
// ... //
<WebView
    scalesPageToFit={true}
    startInLoadingState
    useWebKit
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    allowsInlineMediaPlayback
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
    source={{ uri: '<access link>' }}
    style={{marginTop: 1, width: widthWebview, height: heightWebview }}
    ref={webView}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    cacheEnabled={true}
    onMessage={onMessage}
    onLoadEnd={onLoaded}
  />
```

**Our observations**

- cacheMode props (in React Native WebView) doesn't help with explicit
  permission request issue.

*For native iOS application the persistent permissions for WKWebView appeared in iOS 15:*

- Similar feature request for Swift: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=220416
- Apple update presentation with solution for Swift (at 14:40):
  https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10032/

**Ideally, we would like to:**

1. have a persistent permissions for external URL inside of webview for
   React Native application
2. delegate / copy permissions (to camera) from iOS application level
   to webview

**We would like to know if there any options to achieve the desired behaviour?**
Is it even fundamentally possible for an app to ask permission only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: Upgrade the lib version to react-native-webview@11.15.0

Step 2: Add the below prop

```
mediaCapturePermissionGrantType="grantIfSameHostElsePrompt"
```

This allows iOS to remember the permission decisions and get rid of the initial double-prompt by inheriting the grant from the native layer.

Reference: [Github Release](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/releases/tag/v11.15.0)

Comment: Little note for cross-origin case:

`mediaCapturePermissionGrantType={"grant"}`